# How to remove Server: header from the HTTP response with Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server

I would like to remove the line:

```
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
```

from my server's HTTP responses, but I couldn't find anything other than to modify `include/ap_release.h` and compile Apache myself. I was wondering if there is a way I don't know about?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### You can remove or mask the server identification from the Http-Header by using the [ModSecurity open source web application firewall](https://www.modsecurity.org/).

> #### Server identity masking
>
> One technique that often helps slow
>   down and confuse attackers is the web
>   server identity change. Web servers
>   typically send their identity with
>   every HTTP response in the Server
>   header. Apache is particularly helpful
>   here, not only sending its name and
>   full version by default, but it also
>   allows server modules to append their
>   versions too.
>
> To change the identity of the Apache
>   web server you would have to go into
>   the source code, find where the name
>   "Apache" is hard-coded, change it, and
>   recompile the server. The same effect
>   can be achieved using the
>
> #### SecServerSignature directive:
>
> `SecServerSignature "Microsoft-IIS/5.0"`
>
> It should be noted that although this
>   works quite well, skilled attackers
>   (and tools) may use other techniques
>   to "fingerprint" the web server. For
>   example, default files, error message,
>   ordering of the outgoing headers, the
>   way the server responds to certain
>   requests and similar - can all give
>   away the true identity. I will look
>   into further enhancing the support for
>   identity masking in the future
>   releases of mod_security.
>
> If you change Apache signature but you
>   are annoyed by the strange message in
>   the error log (some modules are still
>   visible - this only affects the error
>   log, from the outside it still works
>   as expected):
>
> `[Fri Jun 11 04:02:28 2004] [notice]
>   Microsoft-IIS/5.0 mod_ssl/2.8.12
>   OpenSSL/0.9.6b \ configured --
>   resuming normal operations`
>
> Then you
>   should re-arrange the modules loading
>   order to allow mod_security to run
>   last, exactly as explained for
>   chrooting.
>
> #### Note
>
> In order for this directive to work
>   you must leave/set ServerTokens to
>   Full.
>
> When the SecServerSignature directive
>   is used to change the public server
>   signature, ModSecurity will start
>   writing the real signature to the
>   error log, to allow you to identify
>   the web server and the modules used.

#### Source: [ModSecurity Reference Manual](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecServerSignature)

Comment: It is running right now but I think it is not smart to use another existing servername because you can trigger attack actions.

Answer (score 30):

If you set `ServerTokens` to "`Prod`", you can reduce the header to "`Server: Apache`". See documentation for full list of options:

[Documentation for Apache 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens)

[Documentation for Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens)

**Note:** The settings are the same in both versions however the 2.4 documentation adds this note:

> Setting ServerTokens to less than minimal is not recommended because it makes it more difficult to debug interoperational problems. Also note that disabling the Server: header does nothing at all to make your server more secure. The idea of "security through obscurity" is a myth and leads to a false sense of safety.

If you want to remove the word "Apache" entirely, you'll have to modify the source.

Comment: +1 tnx for the reply, I forgot to mention in question I was aware of this but I want to have it say Microsoft IIS or something. I should have made that clear.